# Using Meteor, is it possible to have "dynamic routes?"

Tags: meteor

sorry, I'm new to webdev and Meteor and I'm not quite sure of the correct terminology.  I am using Meteor-Router to create routes in my Meteor app.

I'm trying to create a test restaurant app, so an entry in my database might be:

```
name: "Kentucky Fried Chicken"
type: "Fast Food"
```

On the main page of the app, you see a list of restaurants.  But the user can click on any item on that list to get to a more detailed page.

I would rather that the urls don't look like:

/restaurant/123

but more so like:

```
/fast-food/kentucky-fried-chicken
/japanese/sushi-r-us
/italian/some-italian-restaurant-name
```

Is this possible to do with Meteor & Meteor-Router?  Thank you!

Btw, right now my routes are very simple:

```
Meteor.Router.add({
  '/': 'home',
  '/admin': 'admin',
  '/403': 'unauthorized'
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use more complex routes than the one you're using now, like this:

```
Meteor.Router.add({
  '/:type/:restaurant': function(type, restaurantName) {
    var restaurant = Retaurants.findOne({type: type, name: restaurantName});
    Session.set('restaurantFromUrl', restaurant);
    // Now your restaurant is in the "restaurantFromUrl" Session
    return 'restaurantPage';
  }
});
```

The /:type and /:restaurant will be passed into the callback and be whatever you set them to in your URL. Oh, and you might want to add a /show-restaurant/type/name/ also, else all urls (that aren't set up in other routes) that match the patter "/whatever/url" will try to get a restaurant.

Everything you need to know is here: https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router

Oh, and this is just an example. Haven't tested it but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Current route package for Meteor that most people use is: [Iron Router](http://www.github.com/EventedMind/iron-router)