# Meteor & Routing: Clicking through a link works, but loading the page from the same URL doesn't

Tags: routes, meteor

I am using Meteor and Meteor Router to provide routing in my test application.  It is a follow-up to my earlier question: [Using Meteor, is it possible to have "dynamic routes?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17099856/using-meteor-is-it-possible-to-have-dynamic-routes)

Right now, I have implemented the answer provided to me in that question.  My routes look like this now:

```
Meteor.Router.add({
  '/:type/:name': function(type, name) {

    //just checking the type and name are correct!
    console.log("type: " + type);
    console.log("name: " + name);
    var activity = Activities.findOne({name: name});
    Session.set("currentActivity", activity._id);
    return 'itemPage';
  },
  //more entries here
});
```

At this point, the URL in the browser might be something like:

```
http://localhost:3000/bar/someCoolBar
```

This code works perfectly fine when I am on the main page and clicking through a link to get to the itemPage.  The Activitiy.findOne successfully finds the correct activity and I can retrieve the activity._id.

However, if I manually refresh the page or if I manually type in that URL into the browser address bar to go directly to that itemPage, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined client.js:34
Meteor.Router.add./:type/:name client.js:34
(anonymous function) router_client.js:59
(anonymous function) router_client.js:31
_.extend._compute deps.js:129
Deps.Computation deps.js:64
_.extend.autorun deps.js:255
Router._setPageFn router_client.js:23
(anonymous function) index.js:278
next index.js:166
page.dispatch index.js:169
page.replace index.js:148
page.start index.js:103
page index.js:60
(anonymous function) router_client.js:176
ready
```

So I can't understand why this doesn't work.  The console.log of "type" and "name" show the correct values, so I figured the Activity.findOne() should work as expected.  But it doesnt.  This line from the error log above:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined client.js:34
```

corresponds to this line of code from my client.js:

```
Session.set("currentActivity", activity._id);
```

Which tells me that findOne did not find a result and **var activity** is undefined.
Why would the routing work when clicking on a link but not when manually entering the URL in the browser address bar?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Meteor initially loads up on the browser there isn't any data available so you need to be able to account for the case that `activity` returns `null` (for the line before).

```
var activity = Activities.findOne({name: name});
```

Because the data would still be downloaded from the server (and hence there isn't an `_id` yet and therefore the undefined error)

Something like this would be ok:

```
var activity = Activities.findOne({name: name});
if(activity) Session.set("currentActivity", activity._id);
```

You could also use the subscription callbacks to check when the page is loaded/loading and show it on your page

Comment: Thank you for the answer!  Could you clarify on the subscription callback?  I'm not sure how to fit it into this scenario..

Comment: When the subscription callback is called you could use that to identify when all the data is downloaded from the server, i.e `Meteor.subscribe("activities",function() { Session.set("loaded",true)})` then use `Session.get("loaded")` to check whether your app is still loading or is ready in a higher latency environment it helps the user know whats going on if places you use data in your template stay blank too long